# How to set onClick Listener on ZoomageView

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, android-gallery

I am Making gallery app for android in kotlin.I am using ZoomageView for displaying image in fullScreen.I also want to show Menu and bottom for share,add/remove Favorite etc on singel tap of imag click but there is problem with it. If i set setOnClickListener on Holder.`Holder.itemView` it allow me to zoom in and out but it won't show me menu. and if i set setOnClickListener on `sliderImageView`(ZoomageView) it will show menu bur i can no longer zoom in or out the image.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
        android:id="@+id/sliderImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:zoomage_animateOnReset="true"
        app:zoomage_autoCenter="true"
        app:zoomage_autoResetMode="UNDER"
        app:zoomage_maxScale="8"
        app:zoomage_minScale="0.6"
        app:zoomage_restrictBounds="false"
        app:zoomage_translatable="true"
        app:zoomage_zoomable="true"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />


</LinearLayout>
```

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val photoPath: Uri = allImageList[position]
        val slideImageView: ImageView = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.sliderImageView)
        Glide.with(context).load(photoPath).into(slideImageView)

        var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView =
            holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)

        // It allow me to zoom in and out but won't show me Bottom Menu
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            bottomNavigationView.visibility =
                if (bottomNavigationView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        }

        // It show Bottom menu but i can no longer zoom in or out 
        slideImageView.setOnClickListener {
            bottomNavigationView.visibility =
                if (bottomNavigationView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        }

    }
```

I want both zoom in and out image and also show and hide menu on sigle tap/click of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the source code of `com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView`, and I think the reason why the ZoomageView can not perform both tap and zoom at the same time is [this line](https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage/blob/2c8aa69af9ae78fc62245f112f3be807018422b5/zoomage/src/main/java/com/jsibbold/zoomage/ZoomageView.java#L451):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        // if the view is clickable, then it will skip handling zoom gestures
        if (!isClickable() && isEnabled() && (zoomable || translatable)) {
            // Handle the zoom gestures
            ......
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

You can see if the view is `Clickable`, then it will skip handling zoom gestures.

**So, the solution will be:**

- Step 1, set the view to not clickable
- Step 2, since the view is not clickable now, so we are going to use another method to detect the tap gesture and call the raw click listener. For example the following code use the `setOnTouchListener()` and `GestureDetector` to implement.

**Here is the solution code, it seems work perfectly for my test:**

```java
// First define a GestureTap class, just call performClick() when a tap gesture is detected
public class GestureTap extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    View view;
    public GestureTap(View view) {
        super();
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        view.performClick();
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
// set OnClickListener as you want
slideImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Log.e("wangpeiming", "imageView clicked");
        bottomNavigationView.visibility =
                if (bottomNavigationView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
    }
});

// set the view to not clickable, so that it can handle zoom gestures afterward.
slideImageView.setClickable(false);

// use OnTouchListener and gestureDetector to detect tap gesture
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new GestureTap(slideImageView));
slideImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // let the gestureDetector to check and handle if there is a tap gesture
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // must return false so that the view's onTouchEvent() can receive the event and handle zoom gestures.
        return false;
    }
});
```

Hope it helps~